# Regexp for matching quoted and unquoted text with attributes

Tags: ruby, regex

Need little help to form a properly working regexp (in ruby) to match quoted or unquoted strings.

Possibilities that user can give:

```
filename.png title:Title
"file name with spaces" title:Title alt:"Alternative text"
"filename.png" title:"Title"
```

Filename part should come out as one group and everything else as another, e.g.

```
=> 1: filename.png 2: title:Title
=> 1: file name with spaces 2: title:Title alt:"Alternative text"
=> 1: filename.png 2: title:"Title"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `^(\"[\w\. ]+\"|[\w\.]+)(.*)$` work for you?

If the string starts with a quote, you make sure to find another one, or else you disallow any spaces in the file name.

Note that I only allowed word characters `\w`, periods, and (optionally) spaces in your file names. You can replaced `\w\.` with any valid characters (besides quotes) that you want to match.